!pip install smartsheet-dataframe is not working, getting ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'smartsheet' Error
I need to read in data from smartsheet to pandas dataframe. I installed smartsheet-dataframe library, but when I try to import it, getting ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'smartsheet'.
!pip install smartsheet-dataframe
...
...
Downloading smartsheet_dataframe-0.3.4-py3-none-any.whl (5.9 kB)
Installing collected packages: smartsheet-dataframe
Successfully installed smartsheet-dataframe-0.3.4

import smartsheet
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[3], line 1
----> 1 import smartsheet

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'smartsheet'

I am not getting errors saying other dependencies need to be installed as well. Can someone help me with this.

The error you're seeing occurs because the smartsheet package isn't installed. While smartsheet-dataframe can be used on its own or with the smartsheet-python-sdk, since you're trying to import smartsheet, you'll need to install it separately.
To resolve this, install the smartsheet-python-sdk package:
!pip install smartsheet-python-sdk

Also make sure that you've set SMARTSHEET_ACCESS_TOKEN in your environment. Follow this guide to do the same.
This should fix your problem.

I am still getting ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'smartsheet' error

Can you check whether the installation was successful or not using !pip show smartsheet-python-sdk and if yes then maybe restart your environment once and try installing it again.

Try !pip install smartsheet-python-sdk --force-reinstall to reinstall.

You have to also set SMARTSHEET_ACCESS_TOKEN in your environment. Follow this.

!pip show smartsheet-python-sdk is showing the package is installed, tried force-reinstall for which I am getting warning message that normalizer.exe is in installed in C:/.... which is not in PATH. Consider adding this directory to PATH. Could this be an issue?

The system I am working on, I don't have admin privilege

I tried with --user option as well, still the same

Have you tried creating a virtual environment?
